# CIS 194 exercise confusion

Tags: haskell

I am learning Haskell on my own and I got confused by an exercise in a [homework](http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~cis194/hw/03-ADTs.pdf) in CIS 194:

> Exercise 1. Before we can start evaluating Expressions and Statements we need some way to store and look up the state of a variable. We define a State to be a function of type String -> Int. This makes it very easy to look up the value of a variable; to look up the value of
>   "A" in state, we simply call state "A". Whenever we assign a variable, we want to update the program State. Implement the following function:
>   extend :: State -> String -> Int -> State
>
> Hint: You can use the input State as a black box for variables other
>   than the one you are assigning.
>
> Example:
>    let st’ = extend st "A" 5
>    in st’ "A" == 5

I fundamentally don't understand what it's asking and the example. How does this provide a way to look up value of "A"? Since `State` is defined as `type State = String -> Int`, does `extend` have type `String->Int->String->Int->State`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Close. Given

```
type State = String -> Int
extend :: State -> String -> Int -> State
```

the "real" type of `extend` is (note the parentheses)

```
extend :: (String -> Int) -> String -> Int -> (String -> Int)
```

or

```
-- because -> is right-associative
extend :: (String -> Int) -> String -> Int -> String -> Int
```

The first argument to `extend` is a function of type `String -> Int`, not just a `String` value.

---

`extend` isn't meant to look up a value of "A"; it's meant to create a new state in which the value of "A" has a given value. For instance:

```
let st' = let st "A" = 3 in extend st "A" 5 
let st'' = extend "B" 2 st'
```

Looking up "A" in `st'` should produce a value of 5, not 3. Likewise, "B" is not defined in `st'`, but is in `st''`.

```
>>> st' "A"
5
>>> st'' "A"
5
> st' "B"
*** Exception: <interactive>:2:5-15: Non-exhaustive patterns in function st'
>>> st'' "B"
2
```

Comment: Sorry if this is really elementary, but does that mean (in your example) `st "A"` is the `(String->Int)` part (i.e. `State`) of the `extend` type? If yes, then should it be followed by a String?

Comment: Right. In the call `extend st "A" 5`, `st` needs to have type `String -> Int`. In the expression `let st "A" = 3`, I'm using pattern matching to define a partial function `st` that returns 3 on an input of "A". `st` is not defined for any other input value. If you define `extend` properly, `st'` is *also* not defined for any other input, and `st''` is defined only for "A" and "B".

Comment: Actually I was wondering if `st "A"` in `extend st "A" 5` has type (String -> Int), then shouldn't it be followed by a `String` as the type of `extend` is `(String -> Int) [which is st "A"] -> String -> Int ...`

Comment: `extend` has type `State -> String -> Int -> State`, so `extend st` has type `String -> Int -> State`, and `extend st "A"` has type `Int -> State`. That leaves `extend st "A" 2` having type `State`, meaning if you give `extend` and old state, a string, and an integer, you get back a new state.

Comment: @Liumx31 There's no `st "A"` in `extend st "A" 5`: there the function `st` (which has type `String->Int`) is not applied to anything, it is passed as the first argument to `extend`.